# Create custom return type React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is it possible to combine many types into a type/variable that can be referenced to mean a more complex type?

I have this return type:

```
function func(...) : (T|undefined|T[]|undefined[]|(T|undefined)[])
```

I wish to create a variable and assign it to the complex return type and use that when I need to use the complex return type.

```
type customType = (T|undefined|T[]|undefined[]|(T|undefined)[])
function func(...) : customType
```

Comment: I think you might as well not bother with `T[]` and `undefined[]` as you will not be able to get the type inference to figure it is one or the other, you could just have your combined type array and it should be able to infer entry to entry after checking if the entry is defined. `type MyType<T> = T | undefined | Array<T | undefined>;`

Comment: Yep that's what I needed, thanks!